# Trying to understand how to use the any() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to pick many given numbers and compare them to a number I chose, how do i do this using the `any` or `all` command , I tried this and it didn't work, any input would be appreciated:

```
import random

v = int(input("What number are you looking for ?"))
a1 = int(input("What is the first number"))
a2 = int(input("What is the second number"))
a3 = int(input("What is the third number"))
a = random.choice([a1,a2,a3])
b = random.choice([a1,a2,a3])
c = random.choice([a1,a2,a3])
if any ([a, b, c]) == v:
   print('We got a hit')
```

Entering the following, I can't get the `if` to evaluate to `True`:

```
What number are you looking for ?5
What is the first number1
What is the second number2
What is the third number5
>>>
```

How am I using `any` wrong here ? Since the last number is `5` I should of gotten a hit but I get nothing.

Comment: you don't need `any`, you need `if v in [a,b,c]`. Check python documentation to see when to use `any`, `all`.

Comment: Thanks, but what if i need to say if v is bigger than all these numbers or if v is smaller than ANY of these numbers , how do i do that??? maybe the example was not clear .

Comment: I will have 10 values and i would want to say if v is bigger than Any of these values...do something

Comment: I heavily edited your question, OP. I hope the edits make it more clear about what exactly it is that you're asking :-)

Comment: Thanks, what if i want to us > and <...it doesnt work with your method below

Comment: What do you want to check exactly with `<` or `>`?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `any` wrong. To achieve what you want, supply the condition to `any`:

```
if any(v == i for i in [a, b, c]):
   print('We got a hit')
```

This will check that there's a value in the list `[a, b, c]` which equals `v`.

Your approach:

```
any([a, b, c]) == v
```

Will first use `any` to check if any of the elements inside the iterable (`[a, b, c]`) supplied has a truthy value (and it does, all of them do if they're positive integers) and returns the appropriate result `True` indicating that. So:

```
any([a, b, c])
```

will return `True`. Your condition then becomes:

```
True == v
```

which obviously evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Ok thanks its clear, but i am trying to also say if something is bigger or smaller so i cannot use in ...i just started a few weeks ago sorry LOL